# How to remove shadow color behind the textview text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one textview whenever I start typing the color behind the text appear with text so How to remove this color please see below image for reference
[image]

As soon as I start to typing the text was appear with color but as soon as i press space key it is gone, disappear.

**Ex. Take one text view and just type you can see color with text in textview.**

Comment: Post your code about the textView.

Comment: There is no code for this, Simple textview and type on it, you can see there selection behind typing text.

Comment: that is speliing auto-correction... :P

Comment: @FahimParkar Perfect answer, Working now as I set "    self.txtview.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo"

Comment: @DipenChudasama : I will post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because ***Auto-Correction is ON***.

Please follow below code

```
self.txtview.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

text.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a **default behavior** of a UITextView.

It becomes word with **highlighted blue background** when your characters can't find any match word in your phone's dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.txtview.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```